# How can create a method in context that can be accessible by child components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I have a component that renders:

```
<View>
   <SomeContext.Provider value={state}>
        {props.children}
   </SomeContext.Provider>
</View>
```

I don't understand how to create a method accessible in the following way:

```
<View>
   <SomeContext.Provider>
        {(method) =>  
                <Button
                   title={"Magic"}
                   onPress={() => {
                     method()
                   }}
                 ></Button>
        }
   </SomeContext.Provider>
</View>
```

Comment: Hey..You want to pass a method to Button Component

Comment: Do you have a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) we could look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Consumer Component**

You need to consume a context through a `Context.Consumer` that is a direct descendent of the the relevant `Provider`. The docs have decent examples, though they mix class-based and functional components. [Updating Context from a Nested Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component)

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-consumer-passing-method-to-nested-child-forked-u0bi8

```
const initData = {
  data: { a: "Text from Context", b: "2" },
  method: () => {
    console.log("Method called.");
  }
};

const SomeContext = React.createContext();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SomeContext.Provider value={initData}>
      <Content />
    </SomeContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Content() {
  return (
    <div>
      <SomeButton />
    </div>
  );
}

function SomeButton() {
  return (
    <SomeContext.Consumer>
      {({ data, method }) => <button onClick={method}>{data.a}</button>}
    </SomeContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

---

**useContext Hook**

The `useContext` hook is also available, and possibly provides a more familiar pattern. The Consumer of the context still needs to be a descendant of the Provider, but it is accessed via an hook rather than through a Consumer component.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-passing-method-to-nested-child-1fcno

```
const initData = {
  data: { a: "Text from Context", b: "2" },
  method: () => {
    console.log("Method called.");
  }
};

const SomeContext = React.createContext();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SomeContext.Provider value={initData}>
      <Toolbar />
    </SomeContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Toolbar(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <SomeButton />
    </div>
  );
}

function SomeButton() {
  const { data, method } = React.useContext(SomeContext);
  return <button onClick={method}>{data.a}</button>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Context counsumer docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer) actually tells you everything you need to know:

> A React component that subscribes to context changes. This lets you subscribe to a context within a function component.

> Requires a function as a child. **The function receives the current context value** and returns a React node. The value argument passed to the function will be equal to the value prop of the closest Provider for this context above in the tree. If there is no Provider for this context above, the value argument will be equal to the defaultValue that was passed to createContext().

So, in your example you need to pass the method you want to the provider:

```
const method = () => {};

<View>
  <SomeContext.Provider value={{ method }}>
    {props.children}
  </SomeContext.Provider>
</View>
```

And then in the Consumer you can call it like this:

```
<View>
  <SomeContext.Consumer>
    // using destructuring here,
    // so its ({ method }) instead of (method)
    {({ method }) =>  
      <Button
        title={"Magic"}
        onPress={() => method()} />
    }
  </SomeContext.Consumer>
</View>
```

Also, it's important that the consumer component is inside the provider.