# How can I pass state from page to component and back to page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, next.js

Is there a way without using Redux with which I can from my **home.js** page (I'm using hooks not classes) set/use a state, pass it to my component **MyComponent.js** and once a div is clicked inside this component update the state (so for the home.js page as well)?

In **home.js** I have something like:

```
export default function Page({ session, items }) {

  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState('main')
  const handleSelect = (e) => {
    setSelectedTab(e);
  }

  ... // then I return some react-bootstrap tabs, where Tab.Container is like:

   <Tab.Container id="tabs-home" activeKey={selectedTab} onSelect={(e) => handleSelect(e)}>

   ...
}
```

In **MyComponent.js** I tried:

```
export default function MyComponent(props) {

  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState()

  const handleClick = () => {
    setSelectedTab("second");
  }

  ... // and I return something like:

  <div onClick={() => handleClick()} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>blahblah</div>
```

So basically when clicking on the item inside the component I need to change selected tab in the page. I'll then need to pass props as well from the component back to the page, but once I understand how I can pass state I guess is the same process again

Comment: Don't set the state in the child, simply pass the `handleSelect()` handler to the child as a prop

Comment: It works! Didn't know this was even possible.. this way I think I can create another function and do the same for some props I need to pass from the component back to the page

Comment: I'm glad it helped, it definitely opens doors.

Comment: Do you eventually know why it works only at the first click for what concern the props I'm passing? they get correctly logged, every item logs its props on click, but it seems like the component where I pass the handler receives the state only the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick snippet illustrating the concept of holding state in the parent and passing control to children.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState('main');

  const handleState = (e) => {
    console.clear();
    console.log(e.target);
    setState(e.target.id);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Tab id="main" state={state} handleState={handleState} />
      <Tab id="second" state={state} handleState={handleState} />
      <Tab id="third" state={state} handleState={handleState} />
    </div>
  )
}

const Tab = ({ id, state, handleState }) => {

  return (
    <div id={id} className={state === id && 'active'} onClick={handleState}>
      {id}
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not the Tab component containing the clickable div, is MyComponent.js which populates my Sidebar with clickable items, when I click on any of them I'm looking to switch tab inside the home.js page programmatically, as well as passing props based on the item clicked so to populate dynamically the tab content. I guess I need Redux for this sort of stuff

Comment: The theory stands regardless of the specific component; hold state and statehandlers at the appropriate parent level and delegate handling to children accordingly (you can't pass state *up*). Here is an parent/child example using the built in `Context` [How can create a method in context that can be accessible by child components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63606592/how-can-create-a-method-in-context-that-can-be-accessible-by-child-components/63607425#63607425)