# Is possible set state from parent and set state from children at same element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I have a component and I need to update the value from parent (ok), but if the user change the value of the input (children / functional component), I need set this value without pass to parent to re-render children.

See this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-thunder-qvibf?file=/src/App.js

Follow this steps:

1. Set some value on input and see console log
2. Click on button, the input receive new value
3. Change value on input again
4. Click on button, why doesn't work again and set value to input?

I need independent children (functional component or class component), and sometimes I need use parent to set children value, but also keeping the children to change his own state, this is possible?

Comment: here is an example of holding state in parent and passing control to children: [How can I pass state from page to component and back to page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65691901/how-can-i-pass-state-from-page-to-component-and-back-to-page/65692580#65692580)

Comment: Hey @pichard, thx for reply, but on this example, the state is controlled by parent, I need maintain controlled by parent and by children, is possible do this without pass callback to parent re-render children? Thanks.

Comment: I will say firstly that setting state from props is an anti-pattern, it would be better to set/handle the state in a single place. But the reason that your example isn't working is that clicking the button the first time changes `valueParent` and so re-renders, but any subsequent clicks *don't change* the value of `valueParent` and so don't trigger a render. (If you add a timestamp or other new value to the `setValueParent()` call it works as you expect it to)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your example isn't working is that any button clicks after the first don't change the value of the parent state and so don't trigger a render.

Below is a simple snippet that gets around this by adding a unique counter value on each click to always trigger a render, but you could also pass the handler to the child and clear the parent state, or sync it with the child state, waiting for the next button click.

I will say that setting state from props is an anti-pattern and leads to unexpected disconnects (as evidenced by the question); it would be better to set/handle the state in a single place.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [parentValue, setParentValue] = React.useState("");

  const clickCount = React.useRef(0);
  const parentValueHandler = () => {
    setParentValue(`New value from parent ${++clickCount.current}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child parentValue={parentValue} />
      <button onClick={parentValueHandler}>Change value to Parent</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const Child = ({ parentValue }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(parentValue);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setValue(parentValue);
  }, [parentValue]);

  return (
    <input
      type='text'
      name='child'
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```